# {XDEBUG} "The Xdebug extension is not loaded No code coverage will be generate" MAMP

Tags: php, config

When i try to to the 'phpunit -c . --coverage-html mytestdir' i have this error :

"The Xdebug extension is not loaded No code coverage will be generate"

Here the end of my my php.ini ...

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
```

Thanks,

I'm trying to find a solution in all the forums since this morning.

Comment: run `php -i | grep xdebug` to see if extension is loaded

Comment: I just tried... No output for this command.

Comment: Note that CLI might have a different php.ini file. Try `php --ini` to make sure you've added xdebug to the right one.

Comment: macbook-pro-de-*****:***** macbookpro$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: Well there you go. PHP cli is looking for `/etc/php.ini` and not finding one. Set that all up and you'll be good.

Comment: What is the minimal conf of php.ini ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it.

1. First I run `php -i | grep xdebug` in my terminal. If this outputs nothing, then `xdebug` is not loaded
2. If `xdebug` is not loaded, you need to know the exact config file which is being loaded by running `php --ini`. You might get something similar to what is below: (note that i'm running php7)

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/conf
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/conf/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)`

In my case, the configurations are being loaded from `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/conf/php.ini`. Open that file and check if `xdebug` is commented. Uncomment it if it is.

You may also check your `phpinfo()` and open the loaded config file. In my case it is `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini` as shown below:

[image]
Copy the `xdebug` config from it (`/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini` in my case) and paste in the file that shows when you run `php --ini` (`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/conf/php.ini` in my case).

Remember to enable `xdebug` on mamp. Hope this helps someone.

[image]